# How to extend existing type to conform to interface

Tags: go

I have defined an interface `Logger` with these methods:

```
type Logger interface {
    Info(args ...interface{})
    Warn(args ...interface{})
    Error(args ...interface{})
}
```

Now, I would like to extend [log.Logger](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger) type to conform to this interface. Since `log.Logger` doesn't have defined these methods I would need to implement them.

I've tried to extend it with adding new methods:

```
type LoggerImpl log.Logger

func (logger *LoggerImpl) Info(v ...interface{}) {
    logger.Println(v)
}

func (logger *LoggerImpl) Warn(v ...interface{}) {
    logger.Println(v)
}

func (logger *LoggerImpl) Error(v ...interface{}) {
    logger.Println(v)
}
```

But seems like this is the wrong approach as I get an error saying `logger.Println undefined (type *LoggerImpl has no field or method Println)`.

Another solution I've tried is embedding type, but this also returns an error:

```
type LoggerImpl struct {
    log.Logger
}

func (logger *LoggerImpl) Info(v ...interface{}) {
    logger.Println(v)
}

func (logger *LoggerImpl) Warn(v ...interface{}) {
    logger.Println(v)
}

func (logger *LoggerImpl) Error(v ...interface{}) {
    logger.Println(v)
}

func initLogger() *LoggerImpl {
    logger := log.New(os.Stdout, "", log.Lshortfile)

    return logger
}
```

The error I get here is when returning logger from `initLogger` function: `cannot use logger (variable of type *log.Logger) as *LoggerImpl value in return statement`

How can I modify `log.Logger` type to conform to `Logger` interface?

Comment: You can't modify another package's types, but you can embed it in your own type and define the new methods on your type.

Comment: The first version would be fine, all you have to do is type convert your LoggerImpl to log.Logger. Unfortunately you'll run into  trouble with pointers, so use the second approach (but with the correct syntax for embedded fields).

Comment: @Volker Thanks for the comment, but I am not following. Can you elaborate? Thank you

Comment: Both things you tried actually do work. You just got the syntax wrong on both. Fixing it with the second version is easier and avoids pitfalls from pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot define methods for a type declared in a different package. You can, however, define a new type, embed the old type into the new type and define new methods for the new type:

```
type LoggerImpl struct {
   *log.Logger
}


func (logger *LoggerImpl) Error(v ...interface{}) {
    logger.Logger.Println(v)
}

func initLogger() *LoggerImpl {
    logger := &LoggerImpl{Logger:log.New(os.Stdout, "", log.Lshortfile)}

    return logger
}
...
```

Above, `LoggerImpl` contains all the method declared for `log.Logger`, and the methods you explicitly declared in this package.

In general: if you embed a type into another struct, the enclosing struct gets all the methods defined for the embedded type. If you define a new type from another type, the new type gets none of the methods of the base type.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer. Extending methods work this way, but now I am struggling to put it into a method for initializing the logger.

Comment: If I use `*log.Logger` as return value instead of `*LoggerImpl` in `initLogger` function, then I cannot pass this logger as it doesn't have defined these methods.

Comment: You have to return a *LoggerImpl: return &LoggerImpl{Logger:log.New(...)}

Comment: I see you've edited the answer, but this doesn't work for me. I get an error on log.New saying: `cannot use log.New(os.Stdout, "", log.Lshortfile) (value of type *log.Logger) as log.Logger value in struct literal`

Comment: @PeterParada use `*log.New(...` to deref the pointer, or change the embedded type from non-pointer to pointer.

Comment: Thank you, will try later today.